# Unable to remap `btn_middle` to libinput using hwdb

Tags: 22.04, wayland, input-devices, libinput, evdev

I am using a Logitech Trackman Marble Trackball on Ubuntu 22.04, Gnome Shell 42, Wayland.

I wish to simulate a middle mouse click with one of the extra side buttons, but it seems I am able to synthesize any type of button *except* the middle button.

- I have created file at `/etc/udev/hwdb.d/71-logitech-trackman.hwdb` like so:

```
evdev:name:Logitech USB Trackball:*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_90004=btn_middle
```

I then run:

```
sudo systemd-hwdb update
sudo udevadm trigger
```

And physically reconnect the device.

- Running `sudo udevadm info /dev/input/event8 | grep btn_middle` shows that the mapping has taken effect.
- Running `sudo evtest /dev/input/event8` outputs the correct mapping like so:

```
Event: time 1689266776.764313, type 4 (EV_MSC), code 4 (MSC_SCAN), value 90004
Event: time 1689266776.764313, type 1 (EV_KEY), code 274 (BTN_MIDDLE), value 1
```

- However, running `sudo libinput debug-events --device /dev/input/event8` does not emit any output when I press the remapped button (though it does output correct lines for all other events).

Oddly, `libinput` does emit output if I choose any other target event, such as `btn_left`, `btn_right`, or even other buttons that the device does not have, such as `btn_back`, and these clicks are correctly reflected in the GUI. It appears to be only the middle button that cannot be emulated.

The behaviour is the same if I attempt to remap any of the four physical buttons.

What could be preventing the middle mouse button mapping from working?

Comment: Have you explored the second solution here? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/662684/135544

It does not use udev, instead a separate program to remap your side buttons to middle mouse.

My searches show others have been able to remap these exact keys to middle mouse. Any chance you have some other operation/program blocking middle mouse you may have forgotten of?

Comment: @AlwaysTalkingAboutMyDog Thanks, I had tried input-remapper, but sadly it conflicts with scroll-wheel-emulation which I am also using (https://github.com/sezanzeb/input-remapper/issues/124). Certainly, something must be blocking remapping to btn_middle, but I cannot determine what it might be.

Comment: Scroll-wheel-emulation seems suspicious here, there's a good chance it is interfering with the middle-mouse button if you say it conflicts with input-remapper. I think you've identified the problem yourself here - some conflict between scroll-wheel-emulation and other input changers/simulators. Likely not going to resolve this without investigating scroll-wheel-emulation in more detail on how it  captures/blocks/suspends certain mouse clicks under different conditions.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue and i solve it, try change you .hwdb file:

```
evdev:input:*
 KEYBOARD_KEY_90004=btn_middle
```